# How to reuse case query values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, case

I have a following query where I reuse logic to cast timestamp to one unified form. I have records in which date columns look like varchar '2023-12-28' and timestamps as varchars '1646376986'.

I'm parsing them in following way:

```
case
    when
        conclusion_date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'
    then
        conclusion_date
    else
        to_char(to_timestamp(conclusion_date::numeric), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
end as conclusion_date
```

The same logic is being repeated 3 times and I'm concerned about performance and resource issues is there better way to reuse this logic?

```
SELECT id,
       case
           when
               conclusion_date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'
               then
               conclusion_date
           else
               to_char(to_timestamp(conclusion_date::numeric), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
           end as conclusion_date,
       object_name,
       request_id,
       street,
       industry_id,
       object_type_name,
       category_id
from ergrequests
WHERE and (object_name ILIKE '%' || COALESCE(@object_name, '') || '%')
  and (industry_id = @industry_id or 0 = @industry_id)
  and (case
           when
               conclusion_date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'
               then
               conclusion_date
           else
               to_char(to_timestamp(conclusion_date::numeric), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    end)::timestamp between
    case
        when @date_from = '' then '2019-01-01'::timestamp
        else @date_from::timestamp
        end and
    case
        when @date_to = '' then CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        else @date_to::timestamp
        end
order by to_timestamp(
                 case
                     when
                         conclusion_date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'
                         then
                         conclusion_date
                     else
                         to_char(to_timestamp(conclusion_date::numeric), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                     end,
                 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US'
         )
offset $1 limit $2;
```

Comment: You are concerned about performance but you use varchar to store a date and time. To me it looks like performance nor validity is of any concern. Change your data types if you can, solves many (future) issues for you

Comment: try to use CTE.  First, cast whole records and then execute your query

Comment: @FrankHeikens unfortunately I cannot it's legacy code which I have to maintain. But thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CTE and then use it in the SELECT query as follows:

```
-- USE CTE
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT id,
           case
               when
                   conclusion_date ~ '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$'
                   then
                   conclusion_date
               else
                   to_char(to_timestamp(conclusion_date::numeric), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
               end as conclusion_date,
           object_name,
           request_id,
           street,
           industry_id,
           object_type_name,
           category_id
    from ergrequests
    WHERE and (object_name ILIKE '%' || COALESCE(@object_name, '') || '%')
      and (industry_id = @industry_id or 0 = @industry_id)
      )
SELECT * FROM CTE  -- SELECT FROM CTE AND USE THE conclusion_date
WHERE  conclusion_date::timestamp between
    case
        when @date_from = '' then '2019-01-01'::timestamp
        else @date_from::timestamp
        end and
    case
        when @date_to = '' then CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        else @date_to::timestamp
        end
order by to_timestamp(
                 conclusion_date,
                 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US'
         )
offset $1 limit $2;
```

Please note that this will not guarantee the good performance but yes, complexity of the query is reduced.